Using AWS ALB together with a Reverse Proxy?
I have the following AWS ECS setup:

Each Frontend Container runs an nginx to serve the static UI content. The UI makes calls to the backend container. The forum container is self-sufficient.
To achieve load balancing, I am considering using an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). If I use the ALB, do I still need a reverse proxy in this setup?
I am considering whether to use a reverse proxy or if an ALB would suffice.

If you are running on ECS you pretty much have to use a load balancer for this. Where you are thinking about using a reverse proxy in this setup exactly? You could place an Application Load Balancer in front of the three ECS services in your diagram without any additional proxies or anything.

If I'm correct, an ALB does not provide static IP addresses, so users cannot directly contact the ALB. My idea was to use an AWS API Gateway in front of the ALB to provide reverse proxy functionality, such as caching, authentication, and rate limiting. I am unsure if the ALB provides this functionalities on its own.

An ALB provides a DNS name, which users can use to directly access it. It sounds like you probably want to use AWS API Gateway in front of these services? Or is there another API Gateway service you are planning to use? Being more specific in your question would be helpful.

AWS API-Gateway did the job. :)
